Updating database records in DDD is susceptible to lost update problem
I'm learning DDD for the first time, and all over the internet I see a very clean pattern for updating values in the database. It looks something like so

use a repository to fetch an entity object, load into memory
call methods on that entity which updates properties, containing business logic for validation
use a repository to save that entity back to the database

Now the only problem that I see with this approach is having a lost update when concurrent users are attempting to update the same database record.
I know that there are techniques to lock database records such as SQL "SELECT FOR UPDATE"  statements, enabling pessimistic locking. I just want to get a better understanding for how most applications get around this problem, as I have attempted to research it and have not found any direct answers to the question

DDD doesn't concern itself with implementation details, so I don't see how it is relevant here.

Now the only problem that I see with this approach -- There isn't a problem here.  The database locks the record during the UPDATE.  If someone else is editing, generally the last person saving wins.  Most ACID databases don't have the "write uncommitted data" problem you're describing, although it's possible to force this problem (in some databases).

@RobertHarvey The lost update problem is certainly a big concern here. Let me further explain:


select money as money1 from users where name = 'john'


select money as money2 from users where name = 'john'


money1 += 10


money 2 += 20


update users SET money = money1 where name = 'john'


update users SET money = money2 where name = 'john'


We have lost 10 dollars in the process. Maybe you are correct in that DDD is not the correct context to describe this problem, but implementation of DDD often follow this pattern


I just want to get a better understanding for how most applications get around this problem, as I have attempted to research it and have not found any direct answers to the question

Common answers:

Forbid concurrent access; arrange your code so that there is one-and-only-one active "process" with permission to write to an entity.  Leader election protocols, for example.

Locking; which is to say allow concurrent access to the storage appliance, but require that a process competes to acquire a "lock" before executing its logic.

Conditional writes; which is to say that we allow unlocked concurrent access to the information in the storage appliance, but changing stored information is done via a compare-and-swap operation.


